# XSLT normalize space from external document

Tags: html, xslt

I have a xslt template that embeds the body of external HTML files into the output file.
I use Apache Formatting Objects Processor 2.8 with xslt 3.0 saxonHE 12 processor available.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:fopi="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/intermediate"
                xmlns:nav="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/intermediate/document-navigation"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<xsl:output method="html"
            version="4.0"
            encoding="utf-8"
            indent="no"/>
            
    <xsl:template name="embed-html">
      <xsl:param name="path"/>

      <xsl:copy-of select="document($path)/html:html/html:body/*"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My external html document looks something like this (simplified):

```html
<html
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td
          height="24"
          class="x64"
          width="115"
          style="height: 18pt; width: 86.25pt">
          <a><span 
            style="font-size: 7pt;      
            color: #000000;"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the Output generated by the template is:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td
      height="24"
      class="x64"
      width="115"
      style="height: 18pt; width: 86.25pt">
      <a><span 
        style="font-size: 7pt;      
        color: #000000;"/>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But what i want is a minimized output like

```html
<table><tr><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td height="24" class="x64" width="115" style="height: 18pt; width: 86.25pt"><a><span style="font-size: 7pt; color: #000000;"/></a></td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr></table>
```

---

I already tried wrapping the select into a `normalize-space()` like

```xml
<xsl:template name="embed-html">
  <xsl:param name="path"/>

  <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(document($path)/html/body/*)"/>

</xsl:template>
```

or

```xml
<xsl:template name="embed-html">
  <xsl:param name="path"/>

  <xsl:copy-of select="document($path)/html/body/normalize-space(*)"/>

</xsl:template>
```

but this only leads to a stringing together of the values `Company Contact Country Alfreds Futterkiste Maria Anders Germany Centro comercial Moctezuma Francisco Chang Mexico`

Comment: Do you have `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`? Or do you want to preserve space for the primary input but not for the secondary?

Comment: No i just use `<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>` .
If i write `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` above my template it works! Why is the xsl:output not enough?

Comment: strip space happens during **input parsing**, output indent defines how a result is **serialized**.

Comment: ok thank you. If i change to more complex html i still have output like `<span style="                 font-size: 7pt;                 color: #000000;                 font-weight: 400;                 text-decoration: none;                 text-line-through: none;                    "/>`

Comment: The strange thing is all content before is strip spaced but everything after still has those awful whitespaces

Comment: Can you please try to edit your question to show any code samples, particular when it comes to white space/formatting problems? I am afraid inside of a comment it is too hard to tell how your input looks. It will also help us understand the details if you tell us which XSLT processor you use, how you run the transformation (e.g. command line, API, some editor. Give us any details we need to be able to easily reproduce the exact issue.

Comment: I've edited my question. 
My output is now minimized using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` but there is still whitespace in the `span` element like `<span style="font-size: 7pt;                   color: #000000;"></span>`

I figured out that these whitespaces disappear when i remove `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"` from the `html` tag.

Comment: You seem to confuse normalize-space with indent. The argument to normalize-space is a string, not a node or a sequence. --- Note also that if you do not strip the white-space-only text nodes, then the xsl:copy-of instruction will copy them to the output.

Comment: Part of attribute indentation might be the result of default Saxon settings which tends to indent or put attributes on a new line if there is a certain line length. It is not clear how your XPath `document($path)/html/body/*` can work if the HTML document has a default namespace (e.g. the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"`) unless you also somewhere in the XSLT use e.g. `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"`. Somehow we seen different bits and pieces which don't allow us to reproduce the single issue.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i have again updated my stylesheet. Hope it gets clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy nodes from an input document you copy any white space. You can use `xsl:strip-space elements="*"` to strip white space (between tags/elements) from input documents but that doesn't apply to attribute values like the value of the `style` attribute that has white space and that will be copied.

```
<span 
            style="font-size: 7pt;      
            color: #000000;"/>
```

If you want such white space to be removed/normalized you will need to push the node(s) through a mode that does the necessary removal/stripping/normalization e.g. `<xsl:template match="@style"><xsl:attribute name="style" select="normalize-space(.)"/>`.

I tried two minimal examples, one using a namespace on the input, one not, the result is one line with the attribute value having several spaces in both cases, in my view due to the [attribute value normalization the XML parser](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize) does.

Test case 1: [online fiddle with Saxon 12 HE](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/index-saxon12api.html?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%221.0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Ahtml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2FREC-html40%22%3E%0A%0A%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22html%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20version%3D%224.0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20indent%3D%22no%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%3Cxsl%3Astrip-space%20elements%3D%22*%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy-of%20select%3D%22html%3Ahtml%2Fhtml%3Abody%2F*%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Chtml%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Av%3D%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Avml%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Ao%3D%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Aoffice%3Aoffice%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Ax%3D%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Aoffice%3Aexcel%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2FREC-html40%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Chead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fhead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3ECompany%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3EContact%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3ECountry%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EAlfreds%20Futterkiste%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EMaria%20Anders%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EGermany%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height%3D%2224%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20class%3D%22x64%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3D%22115%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22height%3A%2018pt%3B%20width%3A%2086.25pt%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%3E%3Cspan%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22font-size%3A%207pt%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%23000000%3B%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EFrancisco%20Chang%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EMexico%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

Test case 2: [online fiddle with Saxon 12 HE](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/index-saxon12api.html?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%221.0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%3E%0A%0A%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22html%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20version%3D%224.0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20indent%3D%22no%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%3Cxsl%3Astrip-space%20elements%3D%22*%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy-of%20select%3D%22html%2Fbody%2F*%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Chtml%0A%20%20xmlns%3Av%3D%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Avml%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Ao%3D%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Aoffice%3Aoffice%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Ax%3D%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Aoffice%3Aexcel%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3ECompany%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3EContact%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3ECountry%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EAlfreds%20Futterkiste%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EMaria%20Anders%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EGermany%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height%3D%2224%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20class%3D%22x64%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3D%22115%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22height%3A%2018pt%3B%20width%3A%2086.25pt%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%3E%3Cspan%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22font-size%3A%207pt%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%23000000%3B%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EFrancisco%20Chang%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EMexico%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

Output is one line:

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><tr><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td height="24" class="x64" width="115" style="height: 18pt; width: 86.25pt"><a><span style="font-size: 7pt;                   color: #000000;"/></a></td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: How does it come that the space in the style attribute is removed when I delete `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"` from the HTML file?

Comment: I can't tell what is removed, an XML parser does some attribute value white space normalization, that shouldn't depend on a namespace.

Comment: I checked my result and you are absolutely right. If i remove the namespace then the html just does not get embedded at all. As my output file is very big I was just scanning for the whitespaces that were obviously not there when the whole HTML is missing :D 

I think we can take this issue as solved as the `xsl:strip-space elements="*"` is doing the job i was looking for.

Again thank you!
You are like my personal XSLT angel since you answer almost every question I ask here :)